# Can I use Samsung Core Prime's (SM 360H) lolipop update of Philippines region on Bangladesh region?

Tags: updates, device-firmware

I am using Samsung Core Prime for a while. But It hadn't launched lolipop firmware for till now for Bangladesh region. But a lolipoo update is avaiable for Philippines region.
http://forum.youmobile.org/downloads/?sa=view&down=11137

Can I use this firmware on Bangladesh region?

Answer (score 0):

No sorry you cannot use the lollipop update of the phillipines region in bangladesh because when the companies launch new updates they get the carrier support of regions